# Jquery working in firefox but not working in google chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, video.js

I am trying to make clone of live channel.
I get video of that specific time from database, load it in player. And seek the video player at played time with jquery and don't let the user seek video forward. After calculating deifference of video's current and ending time i set the page to reload itself after that time to load next video.

- My code is working on firefox and internet explorer but not
  on chrome.

Here it is HTML

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<?php echo $reload_sec; ?>" >
<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.8.0/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet"

>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<!-- If you'd like to support IE8 -->
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/1.1.2/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-content container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div align="center" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
                <video id="my-video" class="video-js embed-responsive-item" controls preload="auto" width="840" height="264" data-setup="{}" autoplay="1">
                    <source src="<?php echo base_url('uploads/channelvideos/'.$file) ?>" type='video/mp4'>
                    <p class="vjs-no-js">
                      To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
                      <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
                    </p>
                </video>
            </div>
            <button onclick="setCurTime()" type="button" class="btn btn-info" style="margin-top:5px"><span class="fa fa-television"></span> Live</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <input type="text" name="seektime" id="seektime" value="<?php echo $seek_at; ?>" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.8.0/video.js"></script>
```

Now Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setCurTime()
{
    location.reload(); 
}
var vid = document.getElementById("my-video");
vid.onloadedmetadata = function() 
{
    $(window).on("load", function()
    {
        var seektimej = $("#seektime").val();   
        if (document.getElementById("my-video")) 
        {
            videojs("my-video").ready(function() 
            {
                var myPlayer = this;
                setTimeout(function() 
                {
                    //Set initial time to seeked time
                    myPlayer.currentTime(seektimej);
                    setTimeout(function() 
                    {
                        var currentTime = 0;
                        myPlayer.on("seeking", function(event) 
                        {
                            if (currentTime < myPlayer.currentTime()) 
                            {
                                myPlayer.currentTime(currentTime);
                            }
                        });
                        myPlayer.on("seeked", function(event) 
                        {
                            if (currentTime < myPlayer.currentTime()) 
                            {
                                myPlayer.currentTime(currentTime);
                            }
                        });
                        setInterval(function() 
                        {
                            if (!myPlayer.paused()) 
                            {
                                currentTime = myPlayer.currentTime();
                            }
                        }, 10);
                    }, 50);
                }, 50);
            });
        }
    });
};
</script>
```

Comment: are you seeing any error in console?

Comment: In chrome it does not autoplay and seek video at passed time.

Comment: @user2181397 No any error is not shown there.

Comment: Sometime even it does not prevent users from seeking forward.